# Ubuntu 22.04 install.iso and other VMs won't start in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, amd

I have not had this problem before with VirtualBox so I thought I would share and hope for some answers.

UPDATE: The VMs are working fine on QEMU/KVM.

When loading Ubuntuy 22.04 install .iso or the Kali Linux "prepared" VirtualBox VM (.vbox) image, VirtualBox just shows some boot-up text on the screen and never loads (see image below). The screen content is the same between both virtual machines (Ubuntu .iso and prepared Kali .vbox). I don't see any errors in the `vbox.log` files and ran them through ChatGPT which also didn't identify any errors.

The host is Ubuntu 22.04 with full updates and upgrades. The most recent Virtualbox 7 is installed downloaded from the Oracle website along with Extension Pack. After installing VirtualBox, I did updates and upgrades again, and rebooted.

[image]

The graphics card is `AMD Radeon 780M`. I installed the [AMD Radeon drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers) for the base system Ubuntu 22.04 with no problems. Both VMs were configured with 128 MB of memory for graphics. This happens when using "Safe Graphics" install method for Ubuntu.

Curiously, the Kali preconfigured VM loads custom Kali GRUB, then after selecting the OS to boot, fails with the screen above.

Here is the output of `lscpu`, AMD Ryzen 7. Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  16
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics
    CPU family:          25
    Model:               116
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    CPU max MHz:         6080.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
    BogoMIPS:            7585.63
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall
                          nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good amd_lbr_v2 nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid ap
                         erfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdra
                         nd lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce top
                         oext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba perfmon_v2 ibrs i
                         bpb stibp ibrs_enhanced vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed
                         adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc
                          cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local avx512_bf16 clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt
                          lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold v_vmsave_vml
                         oad vgif x2avic v_spec_ctrl vnmi avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx
                         512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid overflow_recov succor smca flush_l1d
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:        AMD-V
Caches (sum of all):    
  L1d:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                    8 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    16 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
Vulnerabilities:        
  Gather data sampling:  Not affected
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow:  Mitigation; safe RET, no microcode
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced / Automatic IBRS, IBPB conditional, STIBP always-on, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affec
                         ted
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Finally, here is a [pastebin with the vbox.log contents](https://pastebin.com/r7AuEarF)

Any ideas where should start to look for a solution to this?

Comment: Is there maybe a vtpm or secure boot enabled on the vm settings which is not in the os of the VM?

Comment: I have tried with the host bios Secure boot on and off, and virtually every setting in the "System" tab of the VM settings: TPM, Nested VT-X/AMD-V, PAE/NX, Paravirtualization Interface, Nested paging.  No changes.  Logs don't seem to indicate either.  Here is full start log, no obvious errors. https://pastebin.com/4t5stHXa